# Graph Explorer Get Planner Tasks

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

ok, try to make a prototype creating Tasks in planner from ASP.NET webforms
this is really hard 
at the moment stuck in Graph explorer error Message
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/Frczk8wfmEGL---------------
permissions for graph explorer set (User.Readwriteall. Groups.Readwriteall)

got to tasks.office.com
select plan and read planid form uri 
(is this really the way how it works?)

trying the samples in Graph Explorer and get a tipp to got to Stackoverflow

just right now also https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ doesnt work
(worked sometimes before)

Answer (score 0):

a few hours later Graph Explorer works - must be a Microsoft problem
part II of my question
i created the identity part with create project wizard so end up in 2 sections in web config

should both point to same clientid? or should I keep that one generated by visual studio an the other one created by the https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ app?

```
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="496578b3-19d4-4956------ />
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
<add key="ida:Domain" value="ppedv.de" />
<add key="ida:TenantId" value="d044494e-fc77-4ae0-------" />
<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44378/" />
<add key="ClientId" value="496578b3-19d4-4956-------" />
<add key="RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44378/" />
<add key="Tenant" value="common" />
<add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
```